Virtual memory size increases considerably with thread count
In the below C++ code example, each time the user presses the Enter key, a new thread will be created. The thread waits for 10 minutes and then exits. The thread has a std::string object with some data.
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

// Function that each thread will execute
void threadFunction()
{
    std::string str;
    str = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    std::cout << "--------------> Thread created" << std::endl;
    // Sleep for 10 minutes'
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::minutes(10));
    cout << "Thread finished sleeping for 10 minute!" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    char input;
    while (true)
    {
        cout << "Press Enter to create a new thread, or 'q' to quit: ";
        input = getchar(); // Wait for user input

        if (input == '\n')
        {                                     // If Enter key is pressed
            thread newThread(threadFunction); // Create a new thread
            newThread.detach();               // Detach the thread to let it run independently
        }
        else if (input == 'q')
        { // If 'q' is pressed, quit the program
            break;
        }
        // Ignore any other input
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }

    return 0;
}

For each thread, it is observed that the virtual memory is increasing considerably.

This is checked using the 'htop' command.
OS : Ububtu 20.04.6 LTS (Focal Fossa)
gcc: gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.2) 9.4.0

Note: This issue is not observed in Windows (mscv).
Can anyone explain why this happens, and how to address it? What is the root cause, and how can we fix it?

This is perfectly normal and predictable. Moreover, there is nothing to fix, as there is no problem with that. Each thread needs a stack to execute. OS will reserve a large range of virtual memory for the thread, but will not actually allocate physical memory (except if the thread uses megabytes of stack, as sign of bad programming). On a 64-bit system, the virtual memory range is huge.

This issue not observed in windows(mscv). The default stack size is only 1MB on windows. It's usually 8 times that on linux. With that said I am unsure why its this big on you test.

Virtual memory size increases is not necessarily a problem. The virtual memory size can even increase beyond the physical memory size without any problem. Just because memory has been allocated does not men that it is used. It just occupies a slot in a page table but doesn't occupy any physical memory. The OS will only allocate physical memory if you write to an address, as long as it's not written to it doesn't take up any physical resources.

Also remember that memory can be paged out, so even if your process occupies a lot of memory, not all of it may be resident at any given time.  You seem to have a very naive and simplistic view of memory in modern computer systems.

Yet another reason to use threads sparingly. Ideally create no more threads than logical processors in the system.

@rustyx I would rather say, don't create more threads than logical processors for the same task (running in parallel for speed). For different asynchronous tasks, threads are generally easier to use than alternative solutions like callbacks or coroutines.

You can see what's up in a debugger:
#0  __GI___mmap64 (addr=addr@entry=0x0, len=len@entry=134217728, prot=prot@entry=0, flags=flags@entry=34, fd=fd@entry=-1, 
    offset=offset@entry=0) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/mmap64.c:50
#1  0x00007ffff7ab2895 in alloc_new_heap (size=135168, top_pad=<optimized out>, pagesize=4096, mmap_flags=mmap_flags@entry=0)
    at ./malloc/arena.c:518
#2  0x00007ffff7ab29e6 in new_heap (size=size@entry=2904, top_pad=<optimized out>) at ./malloc/arena.c:573
#3  0x00007ffff7ab2db2 in _int_new_arena (size=640) at ./malloc/arena.c:741
#4  arena_get2 (avoid_arena=<optimized out>, size=640) at ./malloc/arena.c:960
#5  arena_get2 (size=640, avoid_arena=<optimized out>) at ./malloc/arena.c:921
#6  0x00007ffff7ab5554 in tcache_init () at ./malloc/malloc.c:3220
#7  0x00007ffff7ab5cfe in tcache_init () at ./malloc/malloc.c:3217
#8  __GI___libc_malloc (bytes=31) at ./malloc/malloc.c:3282
#9  0x00007ffff7cb268c in operator new(unsigned long) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#10 0x00007ffff7d4fe1e in std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_mutate(unsigned long, unsigned long, char const*, unsigned long) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#11 0x00007ffff7d50f0b in std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_replace(unsigned long, unsigned long, char const*, unsigned long) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#12 0x0000555555555254 in threadFunction() ()

glibc is allocating a new thread-local arena for each thread on its first allocation. If you remove the std::string, no allocation happens, so no arena is created and vspace usage only grows by the size of the stack.
The arena itself is relatively small, but glibc allocates a larger size than necessary for alignment reasons:
  /* A memory region aligned to a multiple of max_size is needed.
     No swap space needs to be reserved for the following large
     mapping (on Linux, this is the case for all non-writable mappings
     anyway). */

